Are bitwise operators faster than logical operators
Should one expect that
flag = (age < 0) | (age > 100)

will execute faster than
flag = (age < 0) || (age > 100)

because the control flow in the || operator slows down instruction pipelining ?
See Branches on
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipelining#Branches

Answering that can only be done for a specific platform, and requires profiling.

Compilers are smart enough to compile these as the same because the short-circuiting doesn't have any observable effect.

Read the generated assembly yourself. The second snippet is by no means necessarily associated with a branch. Compilers are pretty smart these days and C is no longer some glorified assembly.

"Should one expect that ..... will execute faster than" - no

You might be interested in rules of optimization and that premature optimization is the root of all evil.

I remember this being asked before with && and & and then in some specific scenario, & would indeed be faster. The key here is that manual optimization without a specific system in mind is too broad a question.

Is if(A | B) always faster than if(A || B)?

How compilers optimize
There is no difference between the two in practice.
Given the code ...
bool branchless(int age) {
    return age < 0 | age > 100;
}

bool branching(int age) {
    return age < 0 || age > 100;
}

GCC emits (https://godbolt.org/z/8MfKr9Mq9)
branchless(int):
        cmp     edi, 100
        seta    al
        ret
branching(int):
        cmp     edi, 100
        seta    al
        ret

... which is equivalent to:
bool micro_optimized(int age) {
    // check for unsigned wrap-around upon subtracting 100
    return unsigned(age) - 100u < age;
}

To be fair, this relies on the fact that age < 0 is also indicated by the a (above) flag, since a negative age corresponds to an unsigned value much greater than 100.
In other words, you're checking:
age >= UINT_MAX / 2 + 1 || age > 100 // redundant, can be simplified to age > 100

Only one cmp instruction is necessary then.
However, this optimization can be generalized by adding or subtracting something from edi prior to comparison to "shift" the range so that 0 is the lower end.
In any case, no branch is needed.
Write clean code, don't micro-optimize
More generally, you should write code that expresses your intent clearly.
Modern optimizing compilers like GCC and Clang are excellent at finding these micro-optimizations, so you don't have to.
A lot of code that appears branching can be turned into a branchless equivalent.
Furthermore, the cost of branch heavily depends on the specific CPU.
If you're writing portable code, you often don't know the specific CPU your code will run on, so you should let the compiler figure out what kind of instructions are best.
Write clean and idiomatic code, unless proper benchmarks have shown that you need such micro-optimizations.

"the cost of branch heavily depends " on the data distribution too.
